# Copy/Paste from raw file on web into .vim

Tags: vim

I want to grab this [badwolf colorscheme raw file online](https://bitbucket.org/sjl/badwolf/raw/tip/colors/badwolf.vim), and feed it into my ~/.vim/colors/badwolf.vim file. How would I go about this? Using pbcopy/pbpaste?

(Of course, I can simply copy and paste the raw file into the badwolf.vim file, but I want to see if I can just use the CLI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Vim itself, with `:help netrw`:

```
:e https://bitbucket.org/sjl/badwolf/raw/tip/colors/badwolf.vim
:saveas ~/vim/colors/badwolf.vim
```

From Vim itself, with `:help :read`:

```
:e ~/vim/colors/badwolf.vim
:r https://bitbucket.org/sjl/badwolf/raw/tip/colors/badwolf.vim
:w
```

From your shell, with `curl`:

```
$ curl https://bitbucket.org/sjl/badwolf/raw/tip/colors/badwolf.vim -o ~/vim/colors/badwolf.vim
```

From your shell, with `wget`:

```
$ wget https://bitbucket.org/sjl/badwolf/raw/tip/colors/badwolf.vim -O ~/vim/colors/badwolf.vim
```

Comment: Thank you. I amended the path (to /.vim/colors/)

I used wget https://bitbucket.org/sjl/badwolf/raw/tip/colors/badwolf.vim -O ~/.vim/colors/badwolf.vim